# Bash, grep between two lines with specified strings

Tags: regex, bash, grep

example_file.txt:

```
    a43
    <un:Test1 id="U111">
    abc1
    cvb1
    bnm1
    </un:Test1>
    <un:Test1 id="U222">
    abc2
    cvb2
    bnm2
    </un:Test1>
```

I need all lines between `<un:Test1 id="U111">` and first `</un:Test1>` only. Number of these lines is differ from one input file to another input file. I have tried

`grep -E -A100000 '<un:Test1 id=\"U111\">'` example_file.txt | grep -B100000 `'</un:Test1>'`

but it returns all strings bellow `<un:Test1 id="U222">` also. I know that it`s better to use xmlparser to parse such kind of files but it is not allowed to install additional libs to the server so I can use grep, awk, sed etc. only. Help me please.

Comment: Is your input an XML file?

Comment: Yes my input is xml. Could you recommend something more useful to retrieve needed data?

Comment: `xmllint` as suggested by [Kent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40889364/171318) is the way to go for xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
sed -n '/<un:Test1 id="U111">/,/<\/un:Test1>/p' file
```

### update with xmllint

If your input is xml, you can try:

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='Test1'][@id='U111']" file.xml
```

**Note**: If you have different namespaces for same localname ("Test1"), you need add the `namespace-uri()`

Comment: That would include the range borders into the output.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Comment: @EBobrov added xmllint with xpath way, since your file is xml.

Comment: @Kent I can't upvote as long as the sed command is still in this answer. I would like to upvote because of the xmllint piece

Comment: @Kent Thank you. But --xpath is unknown option and when I use --path it gives "namespace warning : xmlns: URI configData.xsd is not absolute". I can`t understand the problem.